# How to prevent a script from doing its calculations when it is not activated?

Tags: pine-script

I have several indicators grouped into one, one of which is based on the bars visible on the chart.

The problem is that if I move the chart and the indicator is not activated (it is on false) then the indicator that groups several indicators is updated to make its calculations. I know that the whole script is read even if some indicators are not activated.

Do you know a way to bypass this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scripts that use the variables of the first or last visible bar will always be recalculated when this interval changes on the chart.

You can move the parts in which you need a dependence on the visible bars into a separate script, then the scripts that do not depend on the visible range will not be recalculated.

If part of the calculations of your indicators from this script is placed in logical blocks inside it, which has a false status, then they will not be calculated. But the general calculation will take place in any case, the separation of indicators into logical blocks will only affect the calculation speed.

There are no other ways